# Power analysis with baseline mean and variance

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, statistical-power

I don't have much familiarity with power analyses but I have seen some online walkthroughs and calculations where the total number of subjects required is calculated using just effect size, alpha, and power (with no reference to mean or variance).

I want to factor the mean and the variance of my current sample into this calculation. I of course do not know what the mean and the variance will be after the intervention has been carried out.

Suppose I carry out an intervention and I want to see if the performance of my subjects improves post intervention relative to pre intervention. I want to look at two cases: 1- Where I am looking at whether my intervention improved the performance of the same subjects. 2- Where I am looking at whether my intervention improved performance where the test group is not the same as the control group. In this case I know the mean and the variance of the control group.

Let me know how to go about carrying this power analysis.

Comment: You say "...with no reference to mean or variance...," but define **_effect size_** and think again. // Also, please provide a specific model. Are you collecting data that will be analyzed using a one-sample t test? One or two-sided alternative?

Comment: but you need the mean of the treatment and control group in that case. that's what i dont understand. do I have to necessarily specify the mean of the treatment group?

Comment: You don't know them. Presumably, that's why you're doing the experiment. The relevant question for determining power is how big a difference is sufficiently large to be of practical importance. You ought to be able to give a reasonable value for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you will do a 'power and sample size' procedure
before collecting data. Suppose you are doing a two-sided, one-sample t test. Then you would need to specify the intended
significance level of the test and the desired power. Also, perhaps based on similar experiments in the past, you would need to guess the population variance $\sigma$ and the difference in means $\Delta = |\mu_0 -\mu_a|$ between null and alternative population means
that you want to be sure to detect.

For a one-sample t test, there is an exact formula involving
a non-central t distribution. Power and sample size procedures in statistical software (and in useful on-line calculators)
use that formula, which can be found in many mathematical statistics texts and some advanced applied statistics texts.

It is also possible to simulate the approximate power for
designated sample size, significance level, $\sigma,$ and $\Delta.$
(Power depends on effect size, which in turn depends on $\sigma$ and $\Delta.)$
Below, let $n = 50,$ $\sigma=10,$ $\Delta = 5.$

*One* such test might be as below: In this one instance
we happen to reject with P-value far below 5%.

```
set.seed(107)
x = rnorm(50, 105, 10)
mean(x);  sd(x)

t.test(x, mu = 100)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 4.3806, df = 49, p-value = 6.225e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
 true mean is not equal to 100
95 percent confidence interval:
 103.1677 108.5375
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 105.8526
```

However, in order to estimate power for sample size $n=50$, we simulate 100,000
such tests and use the proportion of rejections to
estimate the power, which is about 93%.

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
               t.test(rnorm(50,105,10), mu=100)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.93433      # aprx power
```

*Note:* Ordinarily, I would refer you to the Wikipedia page on 'effect size', but as this is written that
Wikipedia page does not seem helpful. Perhaps some of the
links in the margin marked 'Related' will be helpful.

Comment: This is the part that confuses me 

"Also, perhaps based on similar experiments in the past, you would need to guess the population variance σ and the difference in means Δ=|μ0−μa| between null and alternative population means that you want to be sure to detect."

I don't have any idea what delta ought to be. I do know what mu_zero and sigma are based on my current data.

Also would my approach have to be different depending on whether the same subjects are included in the control and treatment group?

Comment: Very few useful experiments are conducted in a total information vacuum.  If your goal is to decrease subjects' weights, over a month would you consider one ounce (30g) to be important, one pound (.5kg) ? ten pounds (4 or 5kg)?

Comment: That's very reasonable. Thanks!